# Can't get data by id using NodeJS and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, postman

I am new to NodeJs and I want to get some information by id. Here is my code 
The controller :

```
router.get('/machine', function (req, res) {
  Machine.getmachine(req.body, function (err, row) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json(row);
    }
  });
});
```

The SQL part :

```
getmachine: function (Machine, callback) {
   return db.query('SELECT * from machine WHERE id=?', [Machine.id], callback);
},
```

I tried to test it with Postman and I only got `{}` as a result.
Please, can you tell me why I don't get what I want?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If so, could you post an error stack-trace?

Comment: i am testing it with postman and no it doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Check the answer below, your `req.body` is probably `undefined` or `null` because it's a `GET` request. You should use `path variables` or `query params` to pass the id for `GET` requests.

Comment: i used req.query.id and i used res.json(req.query.id); to see if it will return the id or not and it return it but i want to return the informations

Comment: @sohyun can you post your postman screenshot of the request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this instead of reading the body data you should read it as **query**. or else if you are passing as **params** you should user **req.params('id')** to get the id.

```
 router.get('/machine', function (req, res) {
  Machine.getmachine(req.query.id, function (err, row) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json(row);
    }
  });
 });
```

**Edit**

According to the url you provided in the comment you can try something like this.

```
 router.get('/machine:id', function (req, res) {
      Machine.getmachine(req.params.id, function (err, row) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(row);
        }
      });
     });
```

If you managed to get the id to the back-end then the issue must be with in you sql query. try something like this

```
 getmachine: function (Id, callback) {
     return db.query('SELECT * from machine WHERE id=?', Id, callback);
 }
```

Comment: query.id gave me the same result and i tried the req.params which gave me an error

Comment: @sohyun are you using **body-parser** ?. Can you post an image of you postman call?

Comment: i couldn't post an image :( but i used this link : http://localhost:3001/machines/machine?id=10

Comment: i tried     
     return db.query('SELECT * from machine WHERE id=?', Machine.id, callback);
and i got an error then i replaced ? by number and i  got the result . that s mean the code i am using in controller file doen't send the id variable. but i couldn't get why

Comment: @sohyun add a console.log inside **getmachine** method and see whether you are getting the id. go through my edited answer again.

Comment: finally, it worked thank you so much. you really helped me a lot.

Comment: @sohyun awesome. If my answer is correct can select it as the answer? :D

Comment: yeah your answer worked for me but for the path, I used just /machine instead of /machine:id  .